# Bose Sport Earbuds working fine on Windows, but not on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, sound, headphones

I recently bought a pair of Bose Sport Earbuds. My computer is running windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. When I use them with windows they work perfectly, but that is not the case with Ubuntu. Here, they constantly cut the sound flow or stop working for 20-30 seconds at a time! Also, they don't connect automatically once paired. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am guessing they are Bluetooth as at the very end of the question you said paired?

Comment: Yes, David, they are wireless (Bluetooth).